# Datepicker navigation icons issues

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Before I posted here, I searched through other answers and made sure about the images folders being in the cc folder, etc.
I STILL have a problem that on my datepicker, the left and right arrows don't show instead the up arrow shows for both!

When I look at my page in web developer on firefox, in the inspector tab I see the correct icon file being selected when I look at the left arrow, as shown below -

```
element {
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url('images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png');
}
```

My css declarations are -

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
```

What else could I be missing?

Thanks.

P.S.

After reading Kamlesh's answer, I realized that I didn't provide all the info. So I captured a screen shot of the Inspector that shows the datepicker.

[image]

This is how the datepicker looks like -
[image]

and when clicked on it -
[image]

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this 
`.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url('../images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png');
}`

Also be sure icons available on images folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `background-position` for the respective icons. Without background-position it will always display the same default icon. It's an image sprite comprising of all the icons. So in order to use it, you should provide the background-position of that icon

Refer this link:http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/

Notice how they have used `background-position` for different icons.

Answer (score 0):

Serious DUH on my part.

In the craziness of getting the site running, I totally messed up and lost track of the fact that the arrows are button icons!
So, the icons getting messed up were arrow-l and arrow-r because it couldn't find the jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css.

Dang!

Thanks guys and sorry I wasted your time ...